# Можно ли использовать Vowpal Wabbit для распознавания именованных сущностей?

Tags: библиотеки, семантика

Данный модуль используют для мультиклассификации и я задался вопросом - можно ли применить данный модуль для задачи распознавания именованных русскоязычных сущностей?